# Prolog permutations with condition?

Tags: algorithm, list, prolog, conditional-statements, permutation

I have this program to generate all the permutations of a list. The thing is, I need to generate only the permutations in which the consecutive terms have the absolute difference less or equal than 3. Something like:

`[2,7,5] => [2,5,7]` and `[7,5,2]`. `[2 7 5]` would be wrong since `2-7 = -5` and `|-5| > 3`

The permutation program:

```
perm([X|Y],Z):-
    perm(Y,W),
    takeout(X,Z,W).
perm([],[]).

takeout(X,[X|R],R).
takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]):-
    takeout(X,R,S).

permutfin(X,R):-
    findall(P,perm(X,P),R).
```

I know I'm supposed to add the condition somewhere in the perm function but I can't figure out exactly what or where to write.

Comment: Can you explain how your `perm` works, because you make it rather hard. There are more straightforward ways to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more intuitive way to write a permutation is:

```
takeout([X|T],X,T).
takeout([H|L],X,[H|T]) :-
    takeout(L,X,T).
```

Where the first element is the original list, the second the element picked, and the third the list without that element.

In that case the permutation predicate is defined as:

```
perm([],[]).
perm(L,[E|T]) :-
    takeout(L,E,R),
    perm(R,T).
```

this also allows tail-recursion which can imply an important optimization in most Prolog systems.

Now in order to generate only permutations with a consecutive difference of at most three, you can do two things:

- The naive way is *generate and test*: here you let Prolog generate a permutation, but you only accept it if a certain condition is met. For instance:

  ```
  dif3([_]).
  dif3([A,B|T]) :-
      D is abs(A-B),
      D =< 3,
      dif3([B|T]).
  ```

  and then define:

  ```
  perm3(L,R) :-
      perm(L,R),
      dif3(R).
  ```

  This approach is not very efficient: it can be the case that for an exponential amount of permutations, only a few are valid, and this would imply a large computational effort. If for instance the list of elements is `[2,5,7,9]` it will generate all permutations starting with `[2,9,...]` while a more intelligent approach could already see that will never generate a valid solution anyway.
- the other more intelligent approach is *interleaved generate and test*. Here you select only numbers with `takeout3/4` that are valid candidates. You can define a predicate `takeout3(L,P,X,T).` where `L` is the original list, `P` the previous number, `X` the selected number and `T` the resulting list:

  ```
  takeout3([X|T],P,X,T) :-
      D is abs(X-P),
      D =< 3.
  takeout3([H|L],N,X,[H|T]) :-
      takeout3(L,N,X,T).
  ```

  Now we can generate a permutation as follows:

  ```
  perm3([],[]).
  perm3(L,[E|T]) :-
      takeout(L,E,R),
      perm3(R,E,T).

  perm3([],_,[]).
  perm3(L,O,[E|T]) :-
      takeout3(L,O,E,R),
      perm3(R,E,T).
  ```

  Mind we use two versions of `perm3`: `perm3/2` and `perm3/3`, the first is used to generate the first element (using the old `takeout/3`), and `perm3/3` is used to generate the remainder of the permutation using `takeout3/4`.

  The full source code of this approach is:

  ```
  takeout([X|T],X,T).
  takeout([H|L],X,[H|T]) :-
      takeout(L,X,T).

  takeout3([X|T],P,X,T) :-
      D is abs(X-P),
      D =< 3.
  takeout3([H|L],N,X,[H|T]) :-
      takeout3(L,N,X,T).

  perm3([],[]).
  perm3(L,[E|T]) :-
      takeout(L,E,R),
      perm3(R,E,T).

  perm3([],_,[]).
  perm3(L,O,[E|T]) :-
      takeout3(L,O,E,R),
      perm3(R,E,T).
  ```

  Running it with `swipl` gives:

  ```
  ?- perm3([2,7,5],L).
  L = [2, 5, 7] ;
  L = [7, 5, 2] ;
  false.
  ```

  The expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Very documented. Really helped me,

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution. I added the condition in `takeout` to make sure the adjacent items are within 3 of each other:

```
perm([X|Y],Z):-
    perm(Y,W),
    takeout(X,Z,W).
perm([],[]).

check(_,[]).
check(X,[H|_]) :-
    D is X - H,
    D < 4,
    D > -4.

takeout(X,[X|R],R) :-
    check(X,R).
takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]):-
    takeout(X,R,S),
    check(F,R).
```